# Find best k maximum spanning trees of graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Is there any way to calculate best k maximum spanning trees of graph without finding all spanning trees?

Comment: Just google "best k maximum spanning trees"

Comment: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-BIT-92.pdf